# trying work with touch events

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch, raphael

I am using mouse events to draw free line (using Raphael) which is working fine with mouse events but it is not working with touch events. Should I need to replace event.pageX to event.screenX or event.clientX if it is touch event?

```
var board = $("#board");
board.bind("mousedown", _mousedownHandler);
        board.bind("touchstart", _mousedownHandler);
function _drawFreeLineBegin(x, y) {
        board.lineEl.path = _drawOptions.paper.path("M"
                + (x - _drawOptions.offset.left) + ","
                + (y - _drawOptions.offset.top));
        _setNewElementProperties(board.lineEl.path,
                Configuration.getProperties("freeLine"));
            board.bind("mousemove.mmu", _mousemoveHandler);
        board.one("mouseup.mmu", _mouseupHandler);
        board.bind("touchmove.mmu", _mousemoveHandler);
        board.one("touchend.mmu", _mouseupHandler);
    }
function _mousedownHandler(event) {
if(event.type == "touchstart"){
            event = event.touches[0];
        }
_drawFreeLineBegin(event.pageX, event.pageY);
return false;
}

    function _mousemoveHandler(event) {
    if(event.type == "touchmove"){
            event = event.touches[0];
        }
    board.lineEl.path
                        .attr(
                                "path",
                                board.lineEl.path.attr("path")
                                        + "L"
                                        + (event.pageX - )
                                        + ","
                                        + (event.pageY ));
                return true;

}

function _mouseupHandler(event) {
board.unbind(".mmu");
 board.lineEl.path = null;
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the issue, I need to replace event.touches[0]; with event.originalEvent.touches[0];